# Объединить синонимичные метки wi-fi и wifi

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Объединить:

- [wi-fi](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wi-fi) - 43 вопроса;
- [wifi](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wifi) - 86 вопросов.

(по состоянию на 16.10.2016)

Эти метки нужно объединить, так как ими уже отмечены примерно соразмерные параллельные множества вопросов.

Comment: Объединять наверное стоит в сторону [tag:wifi], для симметрии с en.so. Описание у метки есть, но слабоватое.

Comment: @NickVolynkin объединить, конечно, надо. Но хотелось бы ещё понять, почему на enSO выбрали вариант без дефиса, прежде чем выбирать его основным. У меня на этот счет есть гипотеза, что из-за более сложных меток, типа `wifi-direct` или `android-wifi`, но не уверен.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Объединил. Если потребуется поменять целевую метку (сейчас это [wifi](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wifi)), пожалуйста, дайте знать!